# Using loop variable in string for call to system() in C

Tags: c, string, loops

Beginner's question - How do I use k in the command string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
       // make k appear in place of USE_K_HERE
       char argv[] = "./a.out -k USE_K_HERE < test.txt";
       system(argv);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI you're putting "-k <k>" in the wrong place. The shell will try to interpret "-k" and "<k>" as a file name same as it is doing with test.txt. Is -k an option to your a.out program? If so it must appear left of the < symbol.

Comment: Please don't use `void main()`. Main should return int. Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int c, char **v)`

Comment: @koodawg Yes, it is a parameter to ./a.out.  I will change that.

Comment: @wildplasser I will change to int main()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use snprintf in the loop body:

```
char cmd[100];
snprintf( cmd, sizeof(cmd), "./a.out -k %d < test.txt", k );
system(cmd);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: Except the options to a.out must appear before the < symbol (see next comment)

Comment: snprintf( cmd, sizeof(cmd), "./a.out  -k %d < test.txt", k );

Comment: @koodawg: Fixed question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the non-standard `itoa` (integer to alpha) or use the much-preferred `sprintf`:

```
char argv[64]; // for example
sprintf(argv, "./a.out -k %d < test.txt", k);
```